# Select Random item from list in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Im working on a google sheet document to randomly pick a protein and a side dish for weeknight meals based on a selection.  The idea is you select your meat (chicken, beef, pork, etc) and the max amount of calories for the meal and it will select a protein and side dish randomly from a list.  Not sure how to go about writing either the equation or a script to do this though.  Heres what im working with so far:

This is the main page where you select what you want

[image: Selector]

This is the protein sheet that will have all the possible selections, so based on the image above would want to randomly pick a chicken dish with 800 or less calories
[image: Protein Sheet]

And finally this is the side, for this I would want to choose a side that is less than the remaining calories, so if the protein had say 500 calories would want a side with 300 or less:

[image: Sides]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Proteins sheet add E3 =randbetween(1,100) and copy the formula down. On the Side/Vegetables add C3 =randbetween(1,100) and copy down. On the Dinner Generator sheet add this query to A8:

```
=query(Sheet2!A3:E,"select A,B where D contains '"& A3 &"' and B <= "& B3 &" order by E desc Limit 1")
```

and this to A9:

```
=query(Sheet3!A3:C,"Select A,B where B <= ("& B3 &" - "& B8 &") order by C desc Limit 1")
```

And this to A10:

```
=B8+B9
```

I named the sheets Sheet1, Sheet2, and Sheet3. Change the sheet names in the queries as needed. I also used desc in the queries so blanks would be at the bottom allowing the lists to be expanded without having to change the queries. I suggest you change fish entries in column D to Fish instead of Tuna, Salmon, etc. Below is a shared example spreadsheet. Make a copy to test.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17SWtKfzDFDV8OeffR7s5PcmmwRMzu6UKzWK26CX7KDU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Works perfectly, Thanks